# How to Deserialize the Trigger old & newMaps in JSON

Tags: apex, json, future, after-trigger, deserialize

I'm trying to pass the old & newmaps as arguments to a future method using JSON method. I see the below error when it tries to deserialize the data. reference-[Passing SObjects to Future](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/passing-objects-to-future-annotated-methods.html)

> |FATAL_ERROR| System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type `OpportunityLineItem` to `Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>`

//Trigger

```
if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
            if(CheckOpportunityLineItemRecursive_AC.runAfterUpdateOnce()){
                if(!System.isFuture() && !System.isBatch()){
                    String jsonOldMap = JSON.serialize(Trigger.oldMap);
                    String jsonNewMap = JSON.serialize(Trigger.newMap);                       OpportunityLineItemTriggerHandler_AC.OnAfterUpdateAsync(jsonOldMap, jsonNewMap);
                }
            }
```

//Future method

```
 public static void OnAfterUpdateAsync(String strOldMap, String strNewMap){
    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>)JSON.deserialize(strOldMap, System.Type.forName('OpportunityLineItem'));
    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> newMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>)JSON.deserialize(strNewMap, System.Type.forName('OpportunityLineItem')); //do something
```

Please help me find what Im missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the correct type for the second parameter to JSON.deserialize:

```
 Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>)
    JSON.deserialize(strOldMap, Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>.class);
```

Or:

```
Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>)
    JSON.deserialize(strOldMap, System.Type.forName('Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>'));
```

(I would personally recommend the first format to avoid typos).

You can get the type for collections (Map, List, and Set) via the `.class` notation as demonstrated above.

Comment: Thanks much @sfdcfox